# Python3 ctypes c_unit32 endianness

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I'm trying to load PCI config space data into python for evaluation, but am running into an issue with using a c_unit32 for BAR0. I've managed to simplify the issue / script to show c_uint16 behaving as I expect, but the c_uint32 failing. Bar0 must be a c_unit32 as in the actual script, the Bar0 is decoded as a separate struct which uses bits 0-13 for various fields, then bits 14:31 for the lower BAR.

In the script, data is loaded from /sys/pci/bus/devices/x/config, so comes back as a string of hex characters, this is emulated in the example by loading a smaller string to represent only a few of the fields

### Expected:

Input string: "86802010f6710000"

VendorID : 0x8086
DeviceID : 0x1020
Bar0     : 0x71f60000

### Actual:

Input string: "86802010f6710000"

VendorID : 0x8086
DeviceID : 0x1020
Bar0     : 0x71f6

The VendorID and DeviceID fields are correctly swapped. I presume the "0000" is being byte swapped and being put infront of the f671, and the f671 is then byte swapped to be 71f6. The leading 00s are then eliminated creating "0x71f6". This is confirmed if I use "f6710100" which becomes 0x171f6.

---

#### How can I ensure when I use the c_uint32 that it is correctly interpreted as 0x71f60000?

---

Code:

```
from ctypes import *


class PCICfg(Structure):

    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
                ("VendorID", c_uint16),
                ("DeviceID", c_uint16),
                ("Bar0",     c_uint32),
               ]


class PCIUnion(Union):

    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
                ("ConfigSpace", PCICfg),
                ("Bytes",       c_ubyte * sizeof(PCICfg))
               ]


    def from_str(self, input):

        print("Input String: ", input)

        hex_data = bytearray.fromhex(input)

        for x in range(0, len(hex_data)):
            self.Bytes[x] = hex_data[x]


if __name__ == '__main__':

    cfg = PCIUnion()
    cfg.from_str("86802010f6710100")

    print("VID: %s" % hex(cfg.ConfigSpace.VendorID))
    print("DID: %s" % hex(cfg.ConfigSpace.DeviceID))
    print("BA0: %s" % hex(cfg.ConfigSpace.Bar0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is the correct little-endian 32-bit result of your input, but if your input is really a hex representation of little-endian 16-bit words, then treat it that way:

```
from ctypes import *
from binascii import unhexlify

class PCICfg(Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [("VendorID", c_uint16),
                ("DeviceID", c_uint16),
                ("Bar0Hi", c_uint16),
                ("Bar0Lo", c_uint16)]

class PCIUnion(Union):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [("ConfigSpace", PCICfg),
                ("Bytes", c_ubyte * sizeof(PCICfg))]

    def from_str(self, inp):
        print("Input String: ", inp)
        self.Bytes[:] = unhexlify(inp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cfg = PCIUnion()
    cfg.from_str("86802010f6710100")
    print("VID: {:#04x}".format(cfg.ConfigSpace.VendorID))
    print("DID: {:#04x}".format(cfg.ConfigSpace.DeviceID))
    print("BA0: {:#04x}{:04x}".format(cfg.ConfigSpace.Bar0Hi,cfg.ConfigSpace.Bar0Lo))
```

> ```
> Input String:  86802010f6710100
> VID: 0x8086
> DID: 0x1020
> BA0: 0x71f60001
> ```

Comment: @Martin, I suggest making `from_str` a `classmethod` constructor that returns `cls.from_buffer_copy(unhexlify(inp))`.